# ASP.Net MVC5 download file and rediredt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to send file response to download and redirect user ?What would be the steps to follow ?Would appreciate if anyone can give link to resource or an overview.
My scenario is user sends request to download a file action method ,then action method send file to download and redirect user

I tried as follow :

```
 [HttpGet]
     [Authorize]
     public ActionResult DownloadFile()
            {

                var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var invoices = _context.Invoices
.Where(x => x.OwnerId == currentUserId).ToList();

                var directory = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Temp");
                var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");

                var fileName = string.Concat("myfile", "_", timeStamp, ".xlsx");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);

                FileService fs = new FileService();
                var file = fs.GenerateExcelFile(filePath, invoices);

                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    var contentType ="application/excel";
                    return File(filePath ,contentType);

                   // HOW do I send download file and return to view ??

            }
```

Comment: In client-server architecture when you do the response you're done. As far as I understand you can't response a file and also redirect to a different page. You'd rather think in a workaround using Javascript and perhaps Ajax.

Comment: @derloopkat, thank you for the response,I will scratch some related threads on using javascript then.

Answer (score 0):

In your view add this code. It uses jQuery and a web api that returns a file with attachment header. Timeout function is intended to allow some time for the file to be requested from server.

```
<a id="link" href="#">Click here to download</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent browser to follow link
        setTimeout(function () { //Redirected to new page in 2 sec
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost:2981/Home/NewPage'
        }, 2000);
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:2981/api/files/get/';
    });
</script>
```

The web api in my case is a dummy method. The important part is the header. You want the user to be prompted to download the file instead of being redirected to the file. So we need to add **attachment** header.

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string result = "this is the file content";
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        return response;
    }
}
```